# Show hidden nth-child items onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of content which is all viewable on desktop. On mobile, I have hidden some of the content and want to add a button, which on click, would show the hidden content.

I'm aware of how to hide and show `div`'s on click, ie.

```
function showClass(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  var visible = getComputedStyle(elem).display == "block";
  if (!visible) {
    elem.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

But unsure on how to approach this for items that are in the same class that are hidden via `nth-child`?

**Markup:**

```css
@media(max-width: 576px){
  .wrapper:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
.showmore{
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 576px){
  .showmore{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 6</p>
  </div>

  <a class="showmore" onclick="show">Show more</a>

</div>
```

Comment: How about limiting the parent height to some pixel value(eg: 150px) on page load and on click of the SHOW MORE button change the parent height to auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:not()` pseudo-class to only hide the items when the `.show-all` class is not present on the container:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')

const showmore = document.querySelector('.showmore')

showmore.addEventListener('click', () => 
  container.classList.toggle('show-all')
)
```

```css
.showmore{
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 576px){
  .container:not(.show-all) .wrapper:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .showmore{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>test 6</p>
  </div>

  <a class="showmore">Show more</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first change the placement of the "show more" link in the markup, in order to keep a more consistent order of reading.

With this approach you need to hide all the sibling elements of the link and  the `click` event just removes the link itself, showing all the remaining content.

In this example the link is visible under `640px` (open the demo in a full page) and I've also inserted a small fade effect over the text before the link (just remove the linear gradient if you are not interested)

```js
document.querySelector('.showmore').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  this.remove();
})
```

```css
.showmore { 
  display: none;
  margin-top: -5em;
}

.showmore::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff);
}



@media all and (max-width:640px) {
  .showmore { 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }  
  
  .showmore ~ * { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>
  
  <a class="showmore" href="#">Show more</a>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consectetur dolor adisciplit elit sed diam nonummy pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```